# SBT artifact in custom task and scope ignored?

Tags: scala, sbt

In SBT, if I have a task that is supposed to generate a zip/jar/war containing a bunch of files, I'd use the `Defaults.packageTaskSettings` method to set up that task. It'd look as follows:

```
object BuildDef extends Build {

  val makeThings = TaskKey[File]("make-things")

  val defaultMakeSettings = (baseDirectory) map { base => Seq(
    (base / "thingA") -> "thingy",
    (base / "thingB") -> "thingz"
  )}

  val project = Project("stuff", file("."))
    .settings(Defaults.packageTaskSettings(makeThings, defaultMakeSettings): _*)
    .settings(
      artifact in makeThings <<= moduleName{ Artifact(_, "zip", "zip") }
    )
}
```

That works just fine, and generates `stuff_2.9.2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip` in `target` folder.

Now I want to make an alternate version of the `make-things` task, that runs in a different scope, e.g. run proguard and then package things slightly differently. I've added the following settings to the `BuildDef` object:

```
val Scope = config("scope")

val project = ...
  .settings(...)
  .settings(
    Defaults.packageTaskSettings(makeThings in Scope, defaultMakeSettings): _*
  )
  .settings(
    artifact in (Scope, makeThings) <<= 
      moduleName{ n => Artifact(n+".scoped", "zip", "zip") }
  )
```

When I run `scope:make-things` it seems to ignore that setting and use the old one:

```
> show scope:make-things
[info] ...\target\scala-2.9.2\stuff_2.9.2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

**Why is it ignoring my settings?** I hoped it'd have been generating `stuff.scoped_2.9.2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip` instead.

For more info...

```
> show scope:make-things::artifact
[info] Artifact(stuff.scoped,zip,zip,None,List(),None,Map())

> show scope:make-things::artifact-path
[info] ...\target\scala-2.9.2\stuff_2.9.2-0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip
```

I realize that I could probably directly change `artifactPath`, but I am going off of what the xsbt-web-plugin does for its `package-war` task, and it doesn't touch the `artifactPath`. I'd like to do this the "right" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out almost as soon as I posted the question. The key was using the `inConfig` method to wrap the package settings, like this:

```
.settings(
  artifact in (Scope, makeThings) <<= moduleName{Artifact(_,"zip","zip")}
)
.settings(
  inConfig(Scope){
    Defaults.packageTaskSettings(makeThings, defaultMakeSettings)
  }: _*
)
```

I also discovered that the `packageTaskSettings` will modify my artifact by appending the name of the config, as long as I specify my artifact setting *before* the `packageTaskSettings`. Now I get an artifact path of

```
...target\scala-2.9.2\stuff_2.9.2-0.1-SNAPSHOT-scope.zip
```

Comment: Thanks, SO, for being my debugger duckie.